# How can I extend an existing facade in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Given the below, stock standard user model (with one small addition), how can I add the following `name_list` function so it is available through the normal Model facade?

I would like to use it such as:
`User::name_list()`

Note: I understand I could actually just flag the method as `static`, but I'm not looking to access a static method, but a normal method exposed through the ioc container.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $hidden = array('password');
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function name_list() 
    {
            return User::lists("name");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Eloquent scopes instead. Using scopes, you can chain multiple methods.

```
public function scopeName_list($query)
{
   return $query->get()->lists('name');
}

// and then call...
User::name_list();
// or
User::whereActive(true)->name_list();
```

Comment: I always forget about query scopes! Thanks @Andreyco